# Prove that $f$ is an odd function.

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals

The following information has been given to us-

1.$f(x)=\int_0^x g(t) dt$

2.$g(x)$ is a non-zero even function

3.$f(x+5)=g(x)$

How do I prove that $f$ is an odd function?

This is the subpart of a problem and I have arrived at the three results given above from my own working. I am stuck at this part.

Comment: You don't need point $3$.  Just substitute $-x$ for $x$ in $(1)$ and make the change of variables $t=-u$ Then use the fact that $g$ is even.

Comment: I am getting $f(x)=f(-x)$ by doing this. Could you please elaborate this in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $$f(-x)=\int_0^{-x}g(t)\,\mathrm{dt}=-\int_{0}^xg(-u)\,\mathrm{du}=-\int_0^xg(u)\,\mathrm{du}=-f(x)$$

I suspect that the error you made was forgetting to change the limits of integration when you made the change of variables.

Comment: how are you getting the negative sign before, $\int_0^x g(-u) du$

Comment: If $t=-u,$ then $\mathrm{dt=-du}$